# How come these classes are not hidden after category deleted?

Tags: javascript

After the categories and todo items for the corresponding category are deleted, the category name, task counter, and form with add button still show. In other words, the (now-empty) section on the page for that category's items still remain as if it was populated before being deleted. They need to be hidden. Right now they only go away on page refresh.

I tried putting those classes to display none in the code below, but the result is hiding them all the time. You can see what I tried commented out. I also am not sure if I am putting the logic in the right place.

Here is [full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sky-ridtc) Here is a [video demonstrating issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VJfLTBSdPmu5U9TVuOzctEjf5QQuoMK0/view).

```
// Delete Category button maker
const buildDeleteCategoryButton = (category) => {
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.className = 'delete-button';
    deleteButton.innerText = 'x';
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        const div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = 'none';
        categorys = categorys.filter((item) => item.id !== category.id); // Filter removed categories
        addCategoryLocalStorage(categorys);
        todos = todos.filter((item) => item.category !== category.id); // Filter todo lists of removed categories
        addToLocalStorage(todos);
        // input.style.display = 'none';
        // addButton.style.display = 'none';
        // categoryTitle.style.display = 'none';
        // listCountElement.style.display = 'none';
    });
    return deleteButton;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the items are deleted, we can reload our page using `window.location.reload()` function so that our changes are reflected properly.

**Sandbox Link:** [Fixed Code with suggestions](https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-app-bug-forked-6qng5?file=/src/app.js)

Changes made in the below Function:

```
// Delete Category button maker
const buildDeleteCategoryButton = (category) => {
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.className = "delete-button";
  deleteButton.innerText = "x";
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const div = this.parentElement;

    categorys = categorys.filter((item) => item.id !== category.id); // Filter removed categories
    addCategoryLocalStorage(categorys);
    todos = todos.filter((item) => item.category !== category.id); // Filter todo lists of removed categories
    addToLocalStorage(todos);
    div.style.display = "none";

    // Added the following code with some logic, that works fine in your case
    let arrowBtn = deleteButton.previousSibling;

    if (arrowBtn.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
  return deleteButton;
};
```

Comment: Much appreciated Imran :)

Comment: Most Welcome Brother :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in declaring `elements` and `curTodos` in your `.js`.

I fixed your codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-noyce-cwq9w

Comment: I don't think that was the issue. Now it is saying "elements undefined" when clicking the arrow button.

Comment: @StephenW can you refresh codesandbox and check again? I didnt saved it, my bad.

Comment: I updated my question to be better understood. I caused some confusion using the word "filter". Thank you for your help on the other issue I did not know I had.

Comment: Yeah, issue still exists. The (now-empty) section on the page for that category's items still remain if it was populated before being deleted. Edited question above.